# Grab Google-Chrome selection and current URL then compose new email in Mail.app

Tags: google-chrome, email, applescript, automator

I'm (a noob and) trying to put together a script to

1. copy the selected text in Chrome tab
2. copy the tab's url
3. compose new email in OSX Mail.app using:

   1. subject=Look at this, boss!
   2. message: URL  + selection

I've tried with Automator services (Service receives selected text in any app+"new mail message"module) which works great for filling message body but without the corresponding URL, it's near impossible to eventually go back to where the text came from…

Does this make any sense? This would shave hours off of my current workflow (copy/paste…).
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I took a crack at this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This successfully copies the highlighted text to the clipboard
chromeurl() {
    url=$(osascript <<EOT
        tell application "Google Chrome" to return URL of active tab of front window
EOT)
# & requires escaping for the xml
echo ${url/&/&amp;}
}

chrometext() {
    # Assign the clipboard to a variable
    # This avoids overwriting it, as "get copy" is the only way I know to get it out of chrome
    pbrevert=$(pbpaste)
    # Copy selected text in chrome 
    $(osascript <<EOT
        tell application "Google Chrome" to get copy selection of active tab of window 1
EOT)
    pbcapture="$(pbpaste)"

    # Revert clipboard
    echo $pbrevert | pbcopy

    echo $pbcapture
}

content="$(chromeurl) $(chrometext)"

echo $content

osascript -e "tell application \"Mail\" to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:\"Look at this, boss!\", content:\"$content\", visible:true}"
```

*NB - it does what you mentioned but doesn't make the email the front focussed window:*

I also turned it in into an **.app** using Mathias Bynens's - [Appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099)
, which turns bash files into **.app** files.

[Dropbox Link to .app](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/alk3g60x3uvw2kh/AAAkMmj43ggTDg2SqDxZHm3La?dl=0)